# Tooltip in Drop Down Menu Causes Menu to Hide on Mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu, tooltip

I have a drop down menu and in that drop down menu I have images with jQuery tool tips (http://tooltipsy.com/). When you mouseover the image the tooltip shows fine. If you mouse off the image the tooltip disappears and the menu still is there. HOWEVER if you mouse down and your cursor mouses over the tooltip the menu and tooltip will both disappear.

I have looked at the tooltip JS and dont see anything related to actually mousing over the tooltip.

See menu here: http://www.dotatryhards.com/  mouseover "GUIDES" in the nav menu, then mouseover an image. Now you will see the tooltip working, move your mouse down (so it hits the tooltip) and now the whole menu and tooltip will disappear. (But if you mouseover a image with a tooltip and mouse off the tooltip(so your cursor doesnt hit the actual tooltip) the menu will stay and the tooltip will hide nicely))

Tooltip JS: http://www.dotatryhards.com/js/tt.js

Any advice would be great to get these tooltips working properly in my drop down menu. Right now it is a hindrance for anyone using the menu, as it will disappear when they mouse down the menu (it is bound to hit a tooltip)

Answer (score 0):

am Not sure why it is happening but this is what i understood.

("tooltipsy1389")

it seems that the above set of divs are outside of ("dropdown_5columns menul2") and inside BODY, and when you mouseOn $(#tooltipsy1389) it is considering as mouseOut of $(".dropdown_5columns,.menul2").

Comment: It looks like this line in the tooltip js is adding it to bottom of body:        this.$tipsy = $('<div id="tooltipsy' + this.random + '" style="position:absolute;z-index:2147483647;display:none">').appendTo('body'); However I cant figure out how to make it append to the parent div. Any advice?